# question regarding state maintenance

Tags: iphone

I 'm new in state maintenance.
I want to know different methods and examples of it for state maintenance of my project having a multiple views,

Comment: What is the state here? You mean the UI state? like first VC, second VC. What is maintainance here? You mean when user quit the app then come back, it should be in the same state at the time they quit?